# Get Java EE 6 interceptors working (Weld on GlassFish 3.1)

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, aop, interceptor, cdi

I'm working on a project where I want to use Interceptors to log usage of a ManagedBean. As I read in the specs and in many examples it should be possible with the current CDI implementations. The code is mainly copied from examples like the Glassfish JavaEE Tutorial or other sources I found on the web. There is no special implementation in it. It should only log.

What I try was the following:

LoggedInterceptor.java

```
package test.interceptors;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Logged
@Interceptor
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoggedInterceptor() {
    }

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext invocationContext)
        throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
                "Entering method: " + invocationContext.getMethod().getName()
                + " in class "
                + invocationContext.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName());

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

Logged.java

```
package test.interceptors;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({
    METHOD,
    TYPE
})
public @interface Logged {
}
```

WEB-INF/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns    /javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>test.interceptors.LoggedInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

MainController.class

```
// ... All imports
@Named
@SessionScoped
@Logged
public class MainController implements Serializable {
  // Code goes here
}
```

What I get is a class not found Exception from the WELD Resource Loader.

```
    [#|2011-04-04T14:03:37.394+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while loading the app : Error loading class test.interceptors.LoggedInterceptor                                                         
    org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class test.interceptors.LoggedInterceptor                                                                                        
            at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultResourceLoader.classForName(DefaultResourceLoader.java:61)                                                                                                                   
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled$ClassLoader.apply(Enabled.java:67)                                                                                                                                            
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled$ClassLoader.apply(Enabled.java:55)                                                                                                                                            
            at com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingRandomAccessList.get(Lists.java:435)                                                                                                                             
            at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)                                                                                                                                                       
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled.createMetadataMap(Enabled.java:130)                                                                                                                                           
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled.<init>(Enabled.java:100)                                                                                                                                                      
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.Enabled.of(Enabled.java:82)                                                                                                                                                           
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.<init>(BeanDeployment.java:104)                                                                                                                                      
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap$DeploymentVisitor.visit(WeldBootstrap.java:185)                                                                                                                       
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap$DeploymentVisitor.visit(WeldBootstrap.java:156)                                                                                                                       
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startContainer(WeldBootstrap.java:287)                                                                                                                                
            at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:167)                                                                                                                                                 
            at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)                                                                                                                                              
            at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:262)                                                                                                                                   
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)                                                                                                                      
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)                                                                                                                      
            at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)                                                                                                                                 
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)                                                                                                                          
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)                                                                                                                          
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)                                                                                                                         
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)                                                                                                                         
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)                                                                                                          
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)                                                                                                          
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)                                                                                                                                    
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)                                                                                                                                      
            at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)                                                                                                                                   
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)                                                                                                                                   
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)                                                                                                                        
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)                                                                                                                                     
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)                                                                                                                                         
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)                                                                                                                                          
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)                                                                                                                           
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)                                                                                                                    
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)                                                                                                                                  
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)                                                                                                                                   
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)                                                                                                                                    
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)                                                                                                                            
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)                                                                                                                                
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)                                                                                                                                                         
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)                                                                                                                           
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)                                                                                                                              
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)                                                                                                                                                                        
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.interceptors.LoggedInterceptor                                                                                                                      
            at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)                                                                                                                          
            at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)                                                                                                                              
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)                                                                                                                                                        
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)                                                                                                                                                        
            at org.jboss.weld.resources.DefaultResourceLoader.classForName(DefaultResourceLoader.java:52)                                                                                                                   
            ... 42 more
```

Comment: The code looks certainly good. Can you describe your deployment (war? / ear? / structure?) Do you have the chance to push it to JBoss 6?

Comment: @jan-groth Hi, thanks for your reply. The Code is deployed as an ear. The ear includes two EJB Jars and a war-file. The interceptors should be used by the ManagedBeans in the war file. Sorry but Glassfish is mandatory there is no JBoss installation available.

Comment: Try moving the interceptor code into the war and see if it's still not working. There is an classpath issue with Weld and EAR deployments...

Comment: Sorry. Did not wrote this. The Interceptor Code is in the war-file :-( I also tried it from one of the EJB-Jars or from a seperated package. Its not working. But my way is correct to use it in ManagedBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news (well, kind of) - your code works like a charm on my machine (GlassFish 3.1, with Netbeans 7.0 RC1).

Here's what I did:

- Created a new Java EE project in Netbeans (with war module)
- Added support for CDI / JSF 2
- Used your classes (all in the war)
- Filled MainController with something loggable

> package test.web;
>
> import java.io.Serializable; import
>   java.util.Date; import
>   javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
>   import javax.inject.Named; import
>   test.interceptors.Logged;
>
> ```
> @Named
> @Logged
> @SessionScoped
> public class MainController implements Serializable {
>     public void callMe() {
>         System.out.println("called at " + new Date());
>     }
> }
> ```

- Added trivial JSF page

  ```
  <h:form>
      <h:outputText value="hallo" />
      <h:commandButton action="#{mainController.callMe}" label="jo" />
  </h:form>
  ```
- Clicked button and checked output ;-)

> INFO: Entering method: callMe in class
>   test.web.MainController INFO: called
>   at Tue Apr 05 13:41:41 CEST 2011

That's pretty much it. Seems like your project setup is the problem - you might want to start again with a fresh project...?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Next time I will setup a new and reduced to the minimum project myself before I ask. 
Yes it is working as expected. Thanks

Comment: The "solution" described in this answer only works inside an EAR. If you have JAR + WAR in an EAR like in the initial question it won't work this way...

Comment: So you reckon the OP lied when he wrote that it's now working for him? ;)