# glassfish 3.1.2 Can you put CDI Interceptors into Servlets?

Tags: glassfish, cdi, interceptor

[Get Java EE 6 interceptors working (Weld on GlassFish 3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538552/get-java-ee-6-interceptors-working-weld-on-glassfish-3-1/5551396#5551396)

I followed the above example and got it to work (i) in a maven project I created from netbeans
as a "war" and (ii) a maven project I created from netbeans as an "ear".

The latter was trickier as I had to add "empty" beans.xml files also to the ejb jar and the ear. (They were valid beans.xml files but had no interceptors or decorators)

```
./mavenproject2-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/beans.xml   -> empty
./mavenproject2-ejb/src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml -> empty
./mavenproject2-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml -> interceptor for Logged
```

My Logged annotation worked fine when I put it on a stateless bean IN the war.
However it didn't work when I annotated the WebServlet with @Logged. Neither the class
nor the methods.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible ?

Comment: The servlet is within the war? You may need to add it to the EAR as well. That sounds like a BDA issue with the scope of the class wrt the server calling it within an EAR.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. The servlet is in the war. Also the stateless session bean (where I put the annotation)  and the interceptor. All I have in the ejb module is a  dud session bean that I don't even use.  The parent project is called mavenproject2 and contains the 3 modules listed above. It is packaged in an ear file.  I don't understand what you are suggesting I do with the EAR.

Comment: Sorry, add a beans.xml with the interceptor enabled to the EAR.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't have much luck with this setup. I might try something simpler.